# Google Earth API support post deprecation

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Is there any way to have the Google Earth plugin work post deprecation?

I know newer versions of browsers will stop supporting the necessary plugins to run Google Earth plugin but is there a way to use older version of a browser with our own Google Earth Enterprise?  The Google Earth Enterprise should host the API I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only for a limited time. [Google Earth Enterprise will only be supported until March 22, 2017](https://support.google.com/earthenterprise/?hl=en#topic=2802998)